# How to declare default property for a struct

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I want to create my own `Integer` with `struct`.

Here is a simple example of a `Integer` which the return value is forced to between 0 and 255.

*These are pseudocode and C# won't compile it.*

```
struct MyInt{
    private int p;
    default property theInt{  
        set{
            p = value;
        }
        get{
            if(p > 255) return 255; else if( p < 0) return 0;
            return p;
        }
    }
}
```

**My main goal is to use following code :**

```
MyInt aaa = 300;            //Grater than 255
if(aaa == 255) aaa = -300;  //Less than 255
if(aaa == 0) a = 50;
```

Is this possible to do with any .NET language ?  Of course I prefer C#

Comment: Looks okay, although I don't quite get your examples...

Comment: Have you tried to modify your setter by adding it some conditions ?

Comment: You can achieve this, not by declaring a "default property", but by writing an [`implicit` conversion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/z5z9kes2.aspx) between your struct and `int`.

Comment: Lossy implicit conversions are generally a bad idea.

Comment: I'd replace your custom type with `System.Byte` and a `byte ClampToByte(int i)` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I said in my comment, you can use an implicit conversion between your structure and `int`:

```
internal struct MyInt
{
    private int p;

    public int BoundedInt
    {
        // As CodesInChaos points out, the setter is not required here.
        // You could even make the whole property private and jsut use
        // the conversions.
        get
        {
            if (p > 255) return 255;
            if (p < 0) return 0;
            return p;
        }
    }

    public static implicit operator int(MyInt myInt)
    {
        return myInt.BoundedInt;
    }

    public static implicit operator MyInt(int i)
    {
        return new MyInt { p = i };
    }
}
```

You need both the `int`-to-`struct` conversion for when you assign a value and the `struct`-to-`int` conversion for when you compare values.

Comment: Thanks for posting your comment as answer, this will be accepted if there is no better solution.

Comment: Why did you keep the setter of evil?

Comment: 1) It makes the struct mutable 2) setting and then getting doesn't return the original value

Comment: I'd clamp when creating the custom type, not accessing it. Fixes equality, improves performance,...

Answer (score 1):

You assign a value to a *struct* in your code. I don't know what language semantcics you use here but in C#, you can not do that (in VB.NET neither as much as I know).

What you *can* do it what you actually already defined in your code, so define a property and the logic inside its `get` and `set` methods.

Yes, there is an option as Rawling suggests to overwrite cast operator between your struct and integer, but please do not do that, it's *very* confusional and not clear from code what is going on there.

So stand on simple property logic.

```
public struct MyInt{
    private int p = default(int);
    public int theInt{  
        set{
            var v = value; 
            if(v > 255) 
               v  =255; 
            else if(v < 0)
               v = 0;
            p = v;
        }
        get{              
            return p;
        }
    }

}
```

And also please note, that in my example I inverted the logic, I put it into the `set`, as if you develope in a way you presented, at some point your `p`, will not have a value of the property `theInt`, which I would strongly encourage to avoid. If there is a field that holds a property value, it has to be **always** equal to the value caller will get from the property itself. If not, it creates a confusion, and in long run development: a mess.

Comment: "If there is a field that holds a property value, it has to be always equal to the value caller will get from the property" - why?

Comment: @Rawling: I explained my point of view in answer. If I have a *p* that holds a value of the property, it has to have the same value (in the same point of time) as the value I get by calling *myInt* property. Disalignemnt of these values is a source of mess.

Comment: Fair enough, I thought you were expressing it as an absolute rule rather than ... well, what I agree is good practice to stop mess :)

Answer (score 0):

You should use an *implicit conversion operator*, like this:

```
public static implicit operator MyInt(int value)
{
    return new MyInt(value);
}
```

This way, you can use `MyInt a = 10;` and the value of 10 is assigned in the constructor of a that takes the value as a parameter.

You should then proceed by overloading the other operators.

Answer (score 0):

.NET does not provide anything like a "default property"<sup>1</sup>.

As [@Rawling](https://stackoverflow.com/users/215380/rawling) comments you can use implicit conversion operators to allow assignment.

But in the end you can never completely emulate the inbuilt types within compiler and .NET CLI, for instance basic operations on `System.Int32` are single CLI op-codes and literals are held natively.

---

<sup>1</sup> Except within COM interop, but COM in VB (V6 and before) showed why default properties are a bad idea: having to have two keywords (`let` and `set`) for assignment to control when the reference or the default property was assigned.

Comment: Default properties *do* exist in VB.NET but since they require an argument they don’t have the issue you mention. Furthermore, it’s important to realise that VB6’ default property language feature merely attempted to solve the same problem that implicit conversions solve so having both would be redundant anyway.